# GA Event not firing within JQuery click function

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-analytics

I'm trying to fire a GA event on click of a button using JQuery to select the element. Like so:

```
$(conversion_add_to_cart).click(function(){
  ga('send', 'event', 'Tracking', 'conversion', 'add_to_cart');
});
```

If I put the event outside of the click function it fires as expected. The click function certain works as an alert() correctly fires if I put it inside the click function:

```
$(conversion_add_to_cart).click(function(){
  alert('Hello world')
  ga('send', 'event', 'Tracking', 'conversion', 'add_to_cart');
});
```

Still the GA event doesn't fire. Does anybody know why it works outside of the click function but not within it?

Comment: How do you know it doesn't work? Analytics may take a while to actually appear.

Comment: @TomášZato I'm using the analytics debugger to view events firing live on the site.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm are there any errors being thrown? Everything seems good based on your code snippet. Only thing I can think of is it might possibly have something to do with scope, but it seems unlikely. Try changing your function to an arrow function, to rule out the scope issue. So something like

```
$(conversion_add_to_cart).click(() => {
  ga('send', 'event', 'Tracking', 'conversion', 'add_to_cart');
});
```